# C# Delete entire node from XSLT

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xslt

From C# code I want to delete node from XSLT.

Eg. I have below XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template name="URLSpliter">
    <xsl:param name="url" />
    <xsl:variable name="splitURL" select="substring - after($url, '/')" />
    <xsl:if test="contains($splitURL, '/')">
      <xsl:call-template name="URLSpliter">
        <xsl:with-param name="url" select="$splitURL" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not(contains($splitURL, '/'))">
      <xsl:value-of select="$splitURL" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
```

Here I want to delete entire urlsplitter node and all the nodes within URLSplitter

Entire `<xsl:template name="URLSpliter"> ...</template>` should get deleted (All the nodes within + that particular node )

Comment: You mean all the nodes having name equals to "URLSpliter"?

Comment: yes.. all nodes having name="urlsplitter" .. if it is within any node , then also I want to remove that parent node

Comment: There are two different types of nodes that have URLSplitter name. First, <xsl:template name="URLSpliter"> & second - <xsl:call-template name="URLSpliter">. You want to delete both?

Comment: Entire nodes within <xsl:template name="URLSpliter"> and </template> @AnkushJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use linq to xml and remove it like as below

```
 documentRoot
           .Descendants("template")
           .Where(ele=> (string) ele.Attribute("name") == "URLSpliter")
           .Remove();
```

Working sample :

```
XElement documentRoot  = 
              XElement.Parse (@"<ordersreport date='2012-08-01'>
                             <returns>
                              <template name='URLSpliter'>
                              </template>
                              <amount>

                                  <orderid>2</orderid>             
                                  <orderid>3</orderid>
                                  <orderid>21</orderid>
                                  <orderid>23</orderid>
                               </amount>
                             </returns>
                        </ordersreport>");
                documentRoot
               .Descendants("template")
               .Where(ele=> (string) ele.Attribute("name") == "URLSpliter")
               .Remove();


            Console.WriteLine(documentRoot.ToString());
```

Comment: @CSharper - can you try now

Comment: It is not working since it has value in name attribute .. Eg. <xsl:template name="URLSpliter">

Comment: @CSharper - updated code have look and make adjustment as per your xml

Comment: Removing "template" from   .Descendants("template") worked

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will work for you. Just replace the path accordingly.

```
string xsltPath = @"C:\Users\ankushjain\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\XSLTFile.xslt";
string pathToSave = @"C:\Users\ankushjain\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\{0}.xslt";

XmlDocument xslDoc = new XmlDocument();
xslDoc.Load(xsltPath);

XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xslDoc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

var nodesToDelete = xslDoc.SelectNodes("//xsl:template[@name='URLSpliter']", namespaceManager);

if (nodesToDelete != null & nodesToDelete.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = nodesToDelete.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        nodesToDelete[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodesToDelete[i]);
    }
    xslDoc.Save(string.Format(pathToSave, Guid.NewGuid()));
}
```